# Disable main split button in dropdown bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropdown, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to disable the main split button from a bootstrap-vue dropdown but keep the dropdown group enabled

This is the most basic sample code from the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown#split-button-support):

```
<div>
  <b-dropdown split text="Split Dropdown" class="m-2">
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Another action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Something else here...</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

By setting `:disabled="true"` in `<b-dropdown>` disables the whole button and I'm not able to expand the other options.

Using the slot `button-content` ignores the `disabled` property which makes sense because I'm overwriting the content and not the button itself.

```
<template slot="button-content" :disabled="true">Split Dropdown</template>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in this [discussion](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/discussions/6790), there is an easier way to achieve this with no extra code.

```
<b-button-group>
  <b-button disabled>Split dropdown</b-button>
  <b-dropdown>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Another action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Something else here...</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</b-button-group>
```